# Ionic 5 - Angular listen to pinch gesture

Tags: angular, ionic5

I am updating an Ionic 3 application to Ionic 5. In my app I use

```
         this.gesture = new Gesture(this.myElement.nativeElement);
     
         this.gesture.listen();
   
         this.gesture.on('pinchend', pinchEvent => {
           const scale = pinchEvent.scale;
           ......

         });
```

this ultimately to control the zoom of the camera.

In Ionic 5 the angular Gesture is not an option anymore so I tried to use the new Gesture  Controller following the official docs but I cannot get the data I need (scale of the pinch), I think it does not support 2 fingers gesture.

How can I listen to the pinch gesture in Ionic 5 and get information on the scale of the pinch event?

Comment: Did you found the solution yet? I'm also facing this problem.

Comment: Not a direct solution. I ended up installing hammer.js in my application and used it to capture the gesture in a similar fashion as it was done before. In my understanding until Ionic 5 hammer.js was used by ionic itself.

Comment: Yes I also did the same thing. Can you tell me how to implement pinch gesture? I wanna change div size on pinch. I got all the pinch data but I don't know how to implement it.